# In my Create View I am trying to populate data based on user selection of a dropdown menu. when running i am constantly getting the js error popup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I am using mvc .net6

```
    public class CreateReservationVM
    {
        public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }
        public ClientDetailsVM ClientDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class ClientDetailsVM
    {
        public string PrimaryContact { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    }
```

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Reservation.ID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Reservation.CLientID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Reservation.CLientID" id="clientDropdown" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ClientList"></select>
            </div>
            <div id="clientDetails"></div>
            <input id="ClientDetails_PrimaryContact" asp-for="ClientDetails.PrimaryContact" />
            <input id="ClientDetails_PrimaryEmail" asp-for="ClientDetails.PrimaryEmail" />
            <input id="ClientDetails_CategoryID" asp-for="ClientDetails.CategoryID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Reservation.ReservationNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Reservation.ReservationNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Reservation.ReservationNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Reservation.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Reservation.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Reservation.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    <script src="~/js/getClientDetails.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get the client
    var clientDropdown = $('#clientDropdown');

    //  change event handler
    clientDropdown.change(function () {
        // Get the selected client ID
        var selectedClientID = $(this).val();

        // AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Reservations/GetClientDetails',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { clientID: selectedClientID },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // Update the clientDetails
                $('#clientDetails').html(data);

                // Populate the client details fields
                $('#ClientDetails_PrimaryContact').val(data.PrimaryContact);
                $('#ClientDetails_PrimaryEmail').val(data.PrimaryEmail);
                $('#ClientDetails_CategoryID').val(data.CategoryID);
            },
            error: function () {
                // Handle the error
                alert('An error occurred while retrieving client details.');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```
        // GET: Reservations/Create
        public IActionResult Create(int? clientID)
        {
            List<Client> clients = _clientService.GetAllClients().ToList();
            ViewBag.ClientList = new SelectList(clients, "ID", "Name");

            Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
            ClientDetailsVM clientDetailsVM = null;

            if (clientID.HasValue)
            {
                var clientDetails = _clientService.GetClientByID(clientID.Value);
                clientDetailsVM = new ClientDetailsVM
                {
                    PrimaryContact = clientDetails.PrimaryContact,
                    PrimaryEmail = clientDetails.PrimaryEmail,
                    CategoryID = clientDetails.CategoryID
                };
            }

            var viewModel = new CreateReservationVM
            {
                Reservation = reservation,
                ClientDetails = clientDetailsVM
            };

            return View("Create",viewModel);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetClientDetails(int clientId)
        {
            var clientDetails = _clientService.GetClientByID(clientId);

            if (clientDetails == null)
            {
                return NotFound(); // Handle case when client is not found
            }

            // Create an anonymous object with the required client details
            var clientData = new
            {
                PrimaryContact = clientDetails.PrimaryContact,
                PrimaryEmail = clientDetails.PrimaryEmail,
                CategoryID = clientDetails.CategoryID
            };

            return Json(clientData);
        }
```

The goal is to choose a value from the dropdown and then it would populate three textboxes below it based on the user selection

Ive tried to make sure that all my IDs and Names are matching. But Im not really sure where else to go. When I inspect in during run time im getting a 404 error code when i choose an item from the dropdown.

After more debugging I have gotten to the point where I hcan see the data being passed but when i get to the data.PrimaryContact it becomes undefined. Am i missing a naming convention or is there a different weway to reference the object other then data.

Answer (score 0):

since you have 404 error it means that you need to fix your rout or url, you can add clientId to your action route

```
 [HttpGet("{clientId}")]
 public IActionResult GetClientDetails(int clientId)
```

and IMHO it is asways better to send data to get action explicitly (remove "data:...")

```
           url: '/Reservations/GetClientDetails/'+ selectedClientID,
            type: 'GET',
            ...
```